# How can you print cipher text as a hex string?

Tags: python, pycrypto

I use the PyCrypto module to generate a cipher text for a message.

```
>>> a=AES.new("1234567890123456")
>>> m='aaaabbbbccccdddd'
>>> a.encrypt(m)
'H\xe7\n@\xe0\x13\xe0M\xc32\xce\x16@\xb2B\xd0'
```

I would like to have this output like the one by `hashlib`

```
>>> from hashlib import sha1
>>> sha1(m).hexdigest()
'68b69b51da162fcf8eee65641ee867f02cfc9c59'
```

That is, I would need a clean string instead of the string with the hex markers like `\x` and stuff.

Is there any way in PyCrypto to achieve this?

If yes,How can encryption and decryption be performed?

If no, how can I convert the string to the string I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encrypt function returns a Python string, then you can do:

```
a.encrypt(m).encode('hex')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) (or [`binascii.b2a_hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex)):

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> a = AES.new("1234567890123456")
>>> m = 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'
>>> a.encrypt(m)
'H\xe7\n@\xe0\x13\xe0M\xc32\xce\x16@\xb2B\xd0'

>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(a.encrypt(m))
'48e70a40e013e04dc332ce1640b242d0'
```

Comment: @rjv, You can't use `.encode('hex')` in Python 3.x. If you want your code works both in Python 2.x and in 3.x, use `binascii.hexlify`.